# How can i ensure NAT is up before instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

My instances when created by my cloudformation template do not run yum update or install aws-cfn-bootstrap.  I see a timeout in the logs however it works after I login and they have fully booted.

Logs show me they are unable to connect at boot, I think because the natgw hasn't been built yet.  It was working yesterday i have been tweaking since but cannot seem to get it to load anymore.

````
  "Parameters": {
      "ONtestenv": {
          "Description": "env name",
          "Type": "String"
      },
      "ONcidr": {
          "Description": "subs for vpc",
          "Type": "String",
          "Default": "10.0.0.0/16"
      },
      "pubONsubnet": {
          "Description": "pub sub block",
          "Type": "String",
          "Default": "10.0.0.0/24"
      },
      "privONsubnet": {
          "Description": "priv subn clok",
          "Type": "String",
          "Default": "10.0.1.0/24"
      },
      "KeyName": {
          "Description": "Name of an existing EC2 KeyPair to enable SSH access to the instances",
          "Type": "AWS::EC2::KeyPair::KeyName",
          "ConstraintDescription": "must be the name of an existing EC2 KeyPair."
      },
      "SSHLocation": {
          "Description": "The IP address range that can be used to SSH to the EC2 instances",
          "Type": "String",
          "MinLength": "9",
          "MaxLength": "18",
          "Default": "0.0.0.0/0",
          "AllowedPattern": "(\\d{1,3})\\.(\\d{1,3})\\.(\\d{1,3})\\.(\\d{1,3})/(\\d{1,2})",
          "ConstraintDescription": "must be a valid IP CIDR range of the form x.x.x.x/x."
      },
      "InstanceType": {
          "Description": "WebServer EC2 instance type",
          "Type": "String",
          "Default": "t2.micro",
          "AllowedValues": [
              "t2.micro",
              "m1.small",
              "m1.medium",
              "m1.large",
              "m1.xlarge",
              "m2.xlarge",
              "m2.2xlarge",
              "m2.4xlarge"
          ],
          "ConstraintDescription": "must be a valid EC2 instance type."
      }
  },
  "Mappings": {
      "Region2Examples": {
          "us-east-1": {
              "Examples": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/cloudformation-examples-us-east-1"
          },
          "ca-central-1": {
              "Examples": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/cloudformation-examples-us-east-1"
          },
          "us-west-2": {
              "Examples": "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/cloudformation-examples-us-west-2"
          },
          "us-west-1": {
              "Examples": "https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/cloudformation-examples-us-west-1"
          },
          "eu-west-1": {
              "Examples": "https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/cloudformation-examples-eu-west-1"
          },
          "eu-central-1": {
              "Examples": "https://s3-eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/cloudformation-examples-eu-central-1"
          },
          "ap-southeast-1": {
              "Examples": "https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/cloudformation-examples-ap-southeast-1"
          },
          "us-east-2": {
              "Examples": "https://s3-us-east-2.amazonaws.com/cloudformation-examples-us-east-2"
          },
          "sa-east-1": {
              "Examples": "https://s3-sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/cloudformation-examples-sa-east-1"
          },
          "cn-north-1": {
              "Examples": "https://s3.cn-north-1.amazonaws.com.cn/cloudformation-examples-cn-north-1"
          }
      },
      "AWSInstanceType2Arch": {
          "t2.micro": {
              "Arch": "64"
          },
          "m1.small": {
              "Arch": "64"
          },
          "m1.medium": {
              "Arch": "64"
          },
          "m1.large": {
              "Arch": "64"
          },
          "m1.xlarge": {
              "Arch": "64"
          },
          "m2.xlarge": {
              "Arch": "64"
          },
          "m2.2xlarge": {
              "Arch": "64"
          },
          "m2.4xlarge": {
              "Arch": "64"
          },
          "c1.medium": {
              "Arch": "64"
          },
          "c1.xlarge": {
              "Arch": "64"
          },
          "cc1.4xlarge": {
              "Arch": "64HVM"
          },
          "cc2.8xlarge": {
              "Arch": "64HVM"
          },
          "cg1.4xlarge": {
              "Arch": "64HVM"
          }
      },
      "AWSRegionArch2AMI": {
          "us-east-1": {
              "32": "ami-31814f58",
              "64": "ami-1b814f72",
              "64HVM": "ami-0da96764"
          },
          "ca-central-1": {
              "32": "ami-31814f58",
              "64": "ami-b61b96d2",
              "64HVM": "ami-b61b96d2"
          },
          "us-west-2": {
              "32": "ami-38fe7308",
              "64": "ami-30fe7300",
              "64HVM": "NOT_YET_SUPPORTED"
          },
          "us-west-1": {
              "32": "ami-11d68a54",
              "64": "ami-1bd68a5e",
              "64HVM": "NOT_YET_SUPPORTED"
          },
          "eu-west-1": {
              "32": "ami-973b06e3",
              "64": "ami-953b06e1",
              "64HVM": "NOT_YET_SUPPORTED"
          },
          "ap-southeast-1": {
              "32": "ami-b4b0cae6",
              "64": "ami-beb0caec",
              "64HVM": "NOT_YET_SUPPORTED"
          },
          "ap-northeast-1": {
              "32": "ami-0644f007",
              "64": "ami-0a44f00b",
              "64HVM": "NOT_YET_SUPPORTED"
          },
          "sa-east-1": {
              "32": "ami-3e3be423",
              "64": "ami-3c3be421",
              "64HVM": "NOT_YET_SUPPORTED"
          }
      }
  },
  "Resources": {
      "ONtestVPC": {
          "Type": "AWS::EC2::VPC",
          "Properties": {
              "CidrBlock": {
                  "Ref": "ONcidr"
              },
              "Tags": [
                  {
                      "Key": "Name",
                      "Value": {
                          "Ref": "ONtestenv"
                      }
                  }
              ]
          },
          "Metadata": {
              "AWS::CloudFormation::Designer": {
                  "id": "3321d2b3-88cd-4e8f-bef1-b5d0b853ca46"
              }
          }
      },
      "ONIG": {
          "Type": "AWS::EC2::InternetGateway",
          "Properties": {
              "Tags": [
                  {
                      "Key": "Name",
                      "Value": {
                          "Ref": "ONtestenv"
                      }
                  }
              ]
          },
          "Metadata": {
              "AWS::CloudFormation::Designer": {
                  "id": "d5878b9e-87f5-4088-8401-1a60d827a01a"
              }
          }
      },
      "ONgatewayattach": {
          "Type": "AWS::EC2::VPCGatewayAttachment",
          "Properties": {
              "InternetGatewayId": {
                  "Ref": "ONIG"
              },
              "VpcId": {
                  "Ref": "ONtestVPC"
              }
          },
          "Metadata": {
              "AWS::CloudFormation::Designer": {
                  "id": "b654db30-aa3f-4ffe-ab5c-27b9a14be28e"
              }
          }
      },
      "natGW": {
          "Type": "AWS::EC2::NatGateway",
          "Properties": {
              "AllocationId": {
                  "Fn::GetAtt": [
                      "natEIP",
                      "AllocationId"
                  ]
              },
              "SubnetId": {
                  "Ref": "pubsub"
              }
          },
          "Metadata": {
              "AWS::CloudFormation::Designer": {
                  "id": "b030b414-e088-4733-8d0a-bbe426610828"
              }
          }
      },
      "pubsub": {
          "Type": "AWS::EC2::Subnet",
          "Properties": {
              "VpcId": {
                  "Ref": "ONtestVPC"
              },
              "AvailabilityZone": {
                  "Fn::Select": [
                      0,
                      {
                          "Fn::GetAZs": ""
                      }
                  ]
              },
              "CidrBlock": {
                  "Ref": "pubONsubnet"
              },
              "MapPublicIpOnLaunch": false,
              "Tags": [
                  {
                      "Key": "Name",
                      "Value": {
                          "Fn::Sub": "${ONtestenv} pub sub"
                      }
                  }
              ]
          },
          "Metadata": {
              "AWS::CloudFormation::Designer": {
                  "id": "dd0e3e42-3b94-4ffe-a8e3-85690934c839"
              }
          }
      },
      "privsub": {
          "Type": "AWS::EC2::Subnet",
          "Properties": {
              "VpcId": {
                  "Ref": "ONtestVPC"
              },
              "AvailabilityZone": {
                  "Fn::Select": [
                      0,
                      {
                          "Fn::GetAZs": ""
                      }
                  ]
              },
              "CidrBlock": {
                  "Ref": "privONsubnet"
              },
              "MapPublicIpOnLaunch": false,
              "Tags": [
                  {
                      "Key": "Name",
                      "Value": {
                          "Fn::Sub": "${ONtestenv} priv sub"
                      }
                  }
              ]
          },
          "Metadata": {
              "AWS::CloudFormation::Designer": {
                  "id": "4cfc646e-acb2-45ea-a075-596b7453e7d7"
              }
          }
      },
      "natEIP": {
          "Type": "AWS::EC2::EIP",
          "DependsOn": "ONgatewayattach",
          "Properties": {
              "Domain": "vpc"
          },
          "Metadata": {
              "AWS::CloudFormation::Designer": {
                  "id": "c3501a25-dec8-4d5b-a8af-4c8ddc2b8c48"
              }
          }
      },
      "pubroutes": {
          "Type": "AWS::EC2::RouteTable",
          "Properties": {
              "VpcId": {
                  "Ref": "ONtestVPC"
              },
              "Tags": [
                  {
                      "Key": "Name",
                      "Value": {
                          "Fn::Sub": "${ONtestenv} pub routes"
                      }
                  }
              ]
          },
          "Metadata": {
              "AWS::CloudFormation::Designer": {
                  "id": "15610e2e-2838-4b07-9ed0-3339a8ee2c6b"
              }
          }
      },
      "defaultpubroute": {
          "Type": "AWS::EC2::Route",
          "DependsOn": "ONgatewayattach",
          "Properties": {
              "RouteTableId": {
                  "Ref": "pubroutes"
              },
              "DestinationCidrBlock": "0.0.0.0/0",
              "GatewayId": {
                  "Ref": "ONIG"
              }
          },
          "Metadata": {
              "AWS::CloudFormation::Designer": {
                  "id": "2ccd0372-a83b-42cf-8d24-4bf2937f9db2"
              }
          }
      },
      "pubsubrtassoc": {
          "Type": "AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation",
          "Properties": {
              "RouteTableId": {
                  "Ref": "pubroutes"
              },
              "SubnetId": {
                  "Ref": "pubsub"
              }
          },
          "Metadata": {
              "AWS::CloudFormation::Designer": {
                  "id": "871f2e97-ff70-4bcf-a707-07cd7629a070"
              }
          }
      },
      "privroutetable": {
          "Type": "AWS::EC2::RouteTable",
          "Properties": {
              "VpcId": {
                  "Ref": "ONtestVPC"
              },
              "Tags": [
                  {
                      "Key": "Name",
                      "Value": {
                          "Fn::Sub": "${ONtestenv} priv routes"
                      }
                  }
              ]
          },
          "Metadata": {
              "AWS::CloudFormation::Designer": {
                  "id": "e3959861-54ef-41eb-8732-644b3302f1a2"
              }
          }
      },
      "defaultprivroute": {
          "Type": "AWS::EC2::Route",
          "Properties": {
              "RouteTableId": {
                  "Ref": "privroutetable"
              },
              "DestinationCidrBlock": "0.0.0.0/0",
              "NatGatewayId": {
                  "Ref": "natGW"
              }
          },
          "Metadata": {
              "AWS::CloudFormation::Designer": {
                  "id": "0bd7af21-8d8c-4bcb-ac8d-b7a0c1bcc7f1"
              }
          }
      },
      "privsubrtassoc": {
          "Type": "AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation",
          "Properties": {
              "RouteTableId": {
                  "Ref": "privroutetable"
              },
              "SubnetId": {
                  "Ref": "privsub"
              }
          },
          "Metadata": {
              "AWS::CloudFormation::Designer": {
                  "id": "e4a0e22d-b70f-498f-8269-7569a2a260cc"
              }
          }
      },
      "SG": {
          "Type": "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup",
          "Properties": {
              "GroupDescription": "Enable ping and ssh access via port 22 and ALL from VPC CIDR",
              "VpcId": {
                  "Ref": "ONtestVPC"
              },
              "SecurityGroupIngress": [
                  {
                      "IpProtocol": "icmp",
                      "FromPort": "8",
                      "ToPort": "-1",
                      "CidrIp": "0.0.0.0/0"
                  },
                  {
                      "IpProtocol": "tcp",
                      "FromPort": "22",
                      "ToPort": "22",
                      "CidrIp": "0.0.0.0/0"
                  },
                  {
                      "IpProtocol": "icmp",
                      "FromPort": "-1",
                      "ToPort": "-1",
                      "CidrIp": "10.0.0.0/16"
                  },
                  {
                      "IpProtocol": "udp",
                      "FromPort": "1",
                      "ToPort": "65535",
                      "CidrIp": "10.0.0.0/16"
                  },
                  {
                      "IpProtocol": "tcp",
                      "FromPort": "1",
                      "ToPort": "65535",
                      "CidrIp": "10.0.0.0/16"
                  }
              ]
          },
          "Metadata": {
              "AWS::CloudFormation::Designer": {
                  "id": "64176529-142e-41de-a97d-b4306dd2c445"
              }
          }
      },
      "webAutoscalingGroup": {
          "Type": "AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup",
          "Properties": {
              "LaunchConfigurationName": {
                  "Ref": "LaunchConfig"
              },
              "LoadBalancerNames": [
                  {
                      "Ref": "ElasticLoadBalancer"
                  }
              ],
              "MaxSize": 4,
              "MinSize": 2,
              "VPCZoneIdentifier": [
                  {
                      "Ref": "pubsub"
                  }
              ]
          },
          "Metadata": {
              "AWS::CloudFormation::Designer": {
                  "id": "a331154a-b1ca-416c-80d3-651425c8ad8e"
              }
          }
      },
      "webAutoscalePolicy": {
          "Type": "AWS::AutoScaling::ScalingPolicy",
          "Description": "A policy to expand the size of the pool by 1 instance",
          "Properties": {
              "AutoScalingGroupName": {
                  "Ref": "webAutoscalingGroup"
              },
              "AdjustmentType": "ChangeInCapacity",
              "Cooldown": 300,
              "ScalingAdjustment": 1
          },
          "Metadata": {
              "AWS::CloudFormation::Designer": {
                  "id": "77ce9e6f-f50d-4f96-a229-76ffe3bfc32a"
              }
          }
      },
      "webAutoScaleAlarm": {
          "Type": "AWS::CloudWatch::Alarm",
          "Description": "When average bandwidth for the instances exceeds a threshold trigger\nthe policy (increasing instance count by 1)\n",
          "Properties": {
              "AlarmName": {
                  "Fn::Join": [
                      "-",
                      [
                          {
                              "Ref": "AWS::StackName"
                          },
                          "bytes out alarm"
                      ]
                  ]
              },
              "AlarmDescription": "This metric monitors network utilization",
              "ComparisonOperator": "GreaterThanOrEqualToThreshold",
              "EvaluationPeriods": 2,
              "MetricName": "NetworkIn",
              "Namespace": "AWS/EC2",
              "Period": 60,
              "Statistic": "Average",
              "Threshold": 5000,
              "Dimensions": [
                  {
                      "Name": "AutoScalingGroupName",
                      "Value": {
                          "Ref": "webAutoscalingGroup"
                      }
                  }
              ]
          },
          "Metadata": {
              "AWS::CloudFormation::Designer": {
                  "id": "e04f759b-93b9-4072-8966-484a4e953230"
              }
          }
      },
      "LBSecurityGroup": {
          "Type": "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup",
          "Properties": {
              "GroupDescription": "SSH and HTTP inbound, egress to VPC",
              "SecurityGroupIngress": [
                  {
                      "IpProtocol": "tcp",
                      "FromPort": "80",
                      "ToPort": "80",
                      "CidrIp": "0.0.0.0/0"
                  },
                  {
                      "IpProtocol": "tcp",
                      "FromPort": "22",
                      "ToPort": "22",
                      "CidrIp": {
                          "Ref": "SSHLocation"
                      }
                  }
              ],
              "SecurityGroupEgress": [
                  {
                      "IpProtocol": "tcp",
                      "FromPort": 0,
                      "ToPort": 65535,
                      "CidrIp": "0.0.0.0/0"
                  }
              ],
              "VpcId": {
                  "Ref": "ONtestVPC"
              }
          },
          "Metadata": {
              "AWS::CloudFormation::Designer": {
                  "id": "f6b443e1-6c3f-4e3c-bcc4-fbccb527b1f1"
              }
          }
      },
      "ElasticLoadBalancer": {
          "Type": "AWS::ElasticLoadBalancing::LoadBalancer",
          "Properties": {
              "Subnets": [
                  {
                      "Ref": "pubsub"
                  }
              ],
              "CrossZone": "true",
              "Listeners": [
                  {
                      "LoadBalancerPort": "80",
                      "InstancePort": "80",
                      "Protocol": "HTTP"
                  }
              ],
              "HealthCheck": {
                  "Target": "HTTP:80/",
                  "HealthyThreshold": "3",
                  "UnhealthyThreshold": "5",
                  "Interval": "30",
                  "Timeout": "5"
              }
          },
          "Metadata": {
              "AWS::CloudFormation::Designer": {
                  "id": "33772321-0e4d-4a0e-bfc6-e4196b7cdead"
              }
          }
      },
      "InstanceSecurityGroup": {
          "Type": "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup",
          "Properties": {
              "GroupDescription": "SSH inbound, port 80 inbound from the load balancer",
              "SecurityGroupIngress": [
                  {
                      "IpProtocol": "tcp",
                      "FromPort": "80",
                      "ToPort": "80",
                      "CidrIp": {
                          "Ref": "SSHLocation"
                      }
                  },
                  {
                      "IpProtocol": "tcp",
                      "FromPort": "22",
                      "ToPort": "22",
                      "CidrIp": {
                          "Ref": "SSHLocation"
                      }
                  }
              ],
              "VpcId": {
                  "Ref": "ONtestVPC"
              }
          },
          "Metadata": {
              "AWS::CloudFormation::Designer": {
                  "id": "9bed003f-7101-4f65-a41c-175bfa579c08"
              }
          }
      },
      "LaunchConfig": {
          "Type": "AWS::AutoScaling::LaunchConfiguration",
          "Metadata": {
              "Comment": "Install a simple application",
              "AWS::CloudFormation::Init": {
                  "config": {
                      "packages": {
                          "yum": {
                              "httpd": []
                          }
                      },
                      "files": {
                          "/var/www/html/index.html": {
                              "content": {
                                  "Fn::Join": [
                                      "\n",
                                      [
                                          "<img src=\"",
                                          {
                                              "Fn::FindInMap": [
                                                  "Region2Examples",
                                                  {
                                                      "Ref": "AWS::Region"
                                                  },
                                                  "Examples"
                                              ]
                                          },
                                          "/cloudformation_graphic.png\" alt=\"AWS CloudFormation Logo\"/>",
                                          "<h1>Congratulations, you have successfully launched the AWS CloudFormation sample.</h1>"
                                      ]
                                  ]
                              },
                              "mode": "000644",
                              "owner": "root",
                              "group": "root"
                          },
                          "/etc/cfn/cfn-hup.conf": {
                              "content": {
                                  "Fn::Join": [
                                      "",
                                      [
                                          "[main]\n",
                                          "stack=",
                                          {
                                              "Ref": "AWS::StackId"
                                          },
                                          "\n",
                                          "region=",
                                          {
                                              "Ref": "AWS::Region"
                                          },
                                          "\n"
                                      ]
                                  ]
                              },
                              "mode": "000400",
                              "owner": "root",
                              "group": "root"
                          },
                          "/etc/cfn/hooks.d/cfn-auto-reloader.conf": {
                              "content": {
                                  "Fn::Join": [
                                      "",
                                      [
                                          "[cfn-auto-reloader-hook]\n",
                                          "triggers=post.update\n",
                                          "path=Resources.LaunchConfig.Metadata.AWS::CloudFormation::Init\n",
                                          "action=/opt/aws/bin/cfn-init -v ",
                                          "         --stack ",
                                          {
                                              "Ref": "AWS::StackName"
                                          },
                                          "         --resource LaunchConfig ",
                                          "         --region ",
                                          {
                                              "Ref": "AWS::Region"
                                          },
                                          "\n",
                                          "runas=root\n"
                                      ]
                                  ]
                              }
                          }
                      },
                      "services": {
                          "sysvinit": {
                              "httpd": {
                                  "enabled": "true",
                                  "ensureRunning": "true"
                              },
                              "cfn-hup": {
                                  "enabled": "true",
                                  "ensureRunning": "true",
                                  "files": [
                                      "/etc/cfn/cfn-hup.conf",
                                      "/etc/cfn/hooks.d/cfn-auto-reloader.conf"
                                  ]
                              }
                          }
                      }
                  }
              },
              "AWS::CloudFormation::Designer": {
                  "id": "fb6eab98-3a1b-426a-945f-14c25bb99862"
              }
          },
          "Properties": {
              "KeyName": {
                  "Ref": "KeyName"
              },
              "ImageId": {
                  "Fn::FindInMap": [
                      "AWSRegionArch2AMI",
                      {
                          "Ref": "AWS::Region"
                      },
                      {
                          "Fn::FindInMap": [
                              "AWSInstanceType2Arch",
                              {
                                  "Ref": "InstanceType"
                              },
                              "Arch"
                          ]
                      }
                  ]
              },
              "SecurityGroups": [
                  {
                      "Ref": "InstanceSecurityGroup"
                  }
              ],
              "InstanceType": {
                  "Ref": "InstanceType"
              },
              "UserData": {
                  "Fn::Base64": {
                      "Fn::Join": [
                          "",
                          [
                              "#!/bin/bash -xe\n",
                              "yum update -y aws-cfn-bootstrap\n",
                              "/opt/aws/bin/cfn-init -v ",
                              "         --stack ",
                              {
                                  "Ref": "AWS::StackName"
                              },
                              "         --resource LaunchConfig ",
                              "         --region ",
                              {
                                  "Ref": "AWS::Region"
                              },
                              "\n",
                              "/opt/aws/bin/cfn-signal -e $? ",
                              "         --stack ",
                              {
                                  "Ref": "AWS::StackName"
                              },
                              "         --resource WebServerGroup ",
                              "         --region ",
                              {
                                  "Ref": "AWS::Region"
                              },
                              "\n"
                          ]
                      ]
                  }
              }
          }
      }
  },
  "Outputs": {
      "VPC": {
          "Description": "A reference to the created VPC",
          "Value": {
              "Ref": "ONtestVPC"
          }
      },
      "PublicSubnet": {
          "Description": "public subnet",
          "Value": {
              "Fn::Join": [
                  ",",
                  [
                      {
                          "Ref": "pubsub"
                      }
                  ]
              ]
          }
      },
      "PrivateSubnet": {
          "Description": "private subnet",
          "Value": {
              "Fn::Join": [
                  ",",
                  [
                      {
                          "Ref": "privsub"
                      }
                  ]
              ]
          }
      }
  }
}```

I am hoping it will install the simple httpd server but it does not.  I am able to run the exact same command ```yum update -y``` after it's booted and I login to it.
````

Answer (score 1):

You can put a `DependsOn` condition on the Auto Scaling group referencing the `natGW`, so that it won't launch instances until the NAT Gateway is ready.

See: [DependsOn Attribute - AWS CloudFormation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-attribute-dependson.html)

CloudFormation normally figures out "depends on" linkages automatically, based on references from one resource to another (eg a Subnet references a VPC, so CloudFormation waits for the VPC to be ready before creating the Subnet).

However, not all relationships are obvious such as between your Auto Scaling group and the NAT Gateway. For these situations, you can manually add a `DependsOn`.

Answer (score 0):

It can also be beneficial to use multiple stacks. This reduces the number of resource dependencies that need to be specified.

Key things like a NAT Gateway should be in one of the first stacks and then if you put things like an autoscaling group in a stack added later the dependency doesn't have to be specified as the NAT Gateway will already be up from the earlier stack.